# Как преобразовать строку времени в тип std::filesystem::file_time_type?

Tags: c++, std

Есть строка, в которой задано время "22.08.2023 17:07"
Нужно сравнить с временем возвращенным функцией std::filesystem::last_write_time() в цикле.
Видимо нужно преобразовать строку "22.08.2023 17:07" в тип std::filesystem::file_time_type
Подскажите, можно ли это как то сделать?

Comment: Я бы дедовским методом сделал - через `time_t`, `struct tm`, `sscanf` и прочие сишные функции. Строка со временем в локальной таймзоне? Или разбираться с работой с датами, добавленной в C++20

Comment: Я к сожалению язык С++ почти не знаю (обычно пишу на php) но хочу хотя бы немного научиться. Стал разбираться с дедовскими методами. Вроде получается. Но вопрос остается актуальным. Хотелось бы как то разобраться с C++20.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Похоже, не мне одному `chrono` кажется отягощенным и запутанным :) Георгий, простите, но что-то у меня от вашего вопроса "*сравнить с временем возвращенным функцией std::filesystem::last_write_time() в цикле*" осталось легкое ощущение [проблемы XY](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/195342). Вы уверены, что решать вашу главную задачу нужно именно таким способом?..

Comment: @Harry С одной стороны я про нововведения С++20 слышал хорошие вещи, и если разобраться, может оно и хорошо работает. Но у нас собранная MSVC программа, которая через них что-то делала, один раз свалилась из-за того, что, видимо, не смогла скачать (!) информацию о существующих временных зонах (хотя работали мы только с текущей, и `localtime` и прочие как-то обходятся без дополнительной информации). Может это мы где-то ошиблись, может MSVC STL кривой, но выглядело дико.